# Ignore One Part of URL and Match Rest

Tags: google-analytics

I'm new to RegEx and am sure this is an easy one. I looked at similar questions, but being new to RegEx, how it all fits together it still fuzzy.

I want my RegEx to:

1. ignore a single parameter in my URL and match *anything* that pops up in the first two parameters (/purple/cat/)
2. match the specific word (/prices)in the last part of the URL
3. BUT not match the date in the middle/ignore that part (and any other date)

URL string:

```
/purple/cat/2017/prices
```

RegEx:

```
\/.*\/.*(?<!(20[0-17])\/prices$
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this - it matches anything with /purple/cat/ + any 4-digit number + /prices:

```
\/purple\/cat\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\/prices
```

P.S. https://regexr.com/ is useful for playing with regex's.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to match whatever occurs in the /purple/cat bit so it could be

Comment: /blue/tiger
/green/panther
/anything/anything

but ignore the value that's where the date is at /2017/ but include the value at the end /prices/

`/match/match/ignore/match`
`/purple/cat/2017/prices`